# Nodejs + express + OpenId connect with redirect to root

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, openid-connect

I have integrated Passport OpenId Connect (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-openidconnect) in my app with success

```
 passport.use('provider', new OICStrategy({
  issuer: "https://fssfed.stage.ge.com/fss",
  authorizationURL : "https://MYFEDERATIONURL/authorization.oauth2",
  tokenURL : "https://MYFEDERATIONURL/token.oauth2",
  userInfoURL : "https://MYFEDERATIONURL/userinfo.openid",
  callbackURL : "http://MYRETURNURL:5000",
  clientID: "MYSECRET",
  clientSecret: "MYPASSWORD"

  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(accessToken);
    console.log(refreshToken);
    console.log("profile:")
    console.log(profile);
    console.log(done);

    return done(null, profile);
  }
));
```

and

```
  app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url + " " + req.isAuthenticated());
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
/*** HOW TO REDIRECT TO****/
        } else {
            next();
        }
    },passport.authenticate('provider'));


app.use('/secure',express.static(path.join(__dirname, process.env['base-dir'] ? process.env['base-dir'] : '../public')))
```

I have to send static content after authentication, but express cannot redirect to secure area.
Unfortunately my federated provider cannot accept redirect url different from  "http://HOST:PORT/", in other word redirect mus be on the root (callbackURL : "http://MYRETURNURL:5000").

How to say to express please send static content?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by myself

## Step1: install openid-connect

```
$ npm install passport-openidconnect --save
```

## Step2: configure startegy

in app.js

```
passport.use('provider', new OICStrategy({
  issuer: "https://fssfed.stage.ge.com/fss",
  authorizationURL : "https://MYFEDERATIONURL/authorization.oauth2",
  tokenURL : "https://MYFEDERATIONURL/token.oauth2",
  userInfoURL : "https://MYFEDERATIONURL/userinfo.openid",
  callbackURL : "http://MYRETURNURL:5000",
  clientID: "MYSECRET",
  clientSecret: "MYPASSWORD"

  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    return done(null, profile);
  }
));
var OICStrategy = require('passport-openidconnect').Strategy;
```

## Step3: configure routes

```
  //logout route
  app.get('/login',passport.authenticate('provider', {noredirect: false}));
  app.get('/authorize',passport.authenticate('provider', {noredirect: false}),
    function (req, res, next) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });


    app.use('/',
    function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.url + " " + req.isAuthenticated());
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
                next();
            } else {
                res.redirect('/login');
            }
        },
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, process.env['base-dir'] ? process.env['base-dir'] : '../public')));
```